# geom_line connecting the mean of different box plot groups (position identity)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a geom_line that and connects the mean of each single box plot for the within the different groups (side). Please see my code below

```
df<-data.frame(time=as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)), 
               value=as.numeric(c(12, 8,17,13,12, 9, 10, 12, 9, 11, 10.5, 11.4, 10.9,15,7, 11.6, 12, 13)), 
               side=as.factor(c("E","Z","E","Z","E","Z","E","Z","E","Z","E","Z","E","Z","E","Z","E","Z")))

df2 <- ddply(df,.(time,side),summarise, val = mean(value))

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(time), y=value, colour=side))+
geom_point(position="identity",aes(group=side), colour="black")+
geom_boxplot(color="black", position = "identity", aes(fill=side))+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00"))+
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(y = val, group = val))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group by `side` and not by `val`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(time), y=value, colour=side))+
  geom_point(position="identity",aes(group=side), colour="black")+
  geom_boxplot(color="black", position = "identity", aes(fill=side))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00"))+
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(time, val, group = side))
```